# Adding MX records to DNS

Tags: domain-name-system, email, tinydns

Let's say I have a *Computer A* which is running postfix, *Computer B* is running `tinydns`.

On domain `project.domain.com` I'm running *httpd server* and on the other server with DNS (tinydns) have entries like `=project.domain.com:1.2.3.4:86400` and `+project.domain.com:1.2.3.4:86400` where `1.2.3.4` is correct addres for server which runs httpd server.

I also have a postfix mail server on `1.2.3.5` which I'd like to work with the domain  *project.domain.com*.

I'm afraid that if I add another alias like `+project.domain.com:1.2.3.5:86400` to tinydns configuration - it could break.

How should that entry look like? Thank you for any hints.

Answer (score 2):

The syntax for MX records is as following:

```
@fqdn:ip:x:dist:ttl:timestamp:lo
```

Source: http://cr.yp.to/djbdns/tinydns-data.html

After configuring your DNS to use your mail server you have to configure Postfix to work with this domain.

Answer (score 0):

Without trying because I have no TinyDNS, I figure:

```
@project.domain.com:1.2.3.5:3600
```